# Ridiculously Large Derivatives

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics

Assuming $f(x)$ as the position of an object, $f'(x)$ would be the speed of an object. The second derivative would be acceleration, the third jerk. I can only find up to snap, crackle, and pop for the fourth, fifth, and sixth derivatives respectively. Does anybody know the names of derivatives past the sixth? If so, what could they practically be used for?

*EDIT *
I've found a probably unreliable source: lock, then drop.

Comment: "What could they practically be used for?" In principle, 'nice' functions can be really well approximated using these higher derivatives in what is called a Taylor series; for details, see [here](http://www.science.smith.edu/~rhaas/m114-00/chp4taylor.pdf).

Comment: I think the names for derivatives past the sixth are "seventh derivative", "eighth derivative", "ninth derivative", and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth derivative of position, known both as snap and jounce, has [a few applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth,_fifth,_and_sixth_derivatives_of_position#Fourth_derivative_(snap/jounce)) in robotics and transportation. As I understand it, crackle and pop are seldom used and really only have names as a joke.

Despite this, I've seen physicists suggest the names "lock, drop, shot, and put" for the 7th through 10th derivatives of position. I, however, disagree with naming something you are likely to never encounter.